# Appium Server is throwing 'UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 134, signal null' error

Tags: android, adb, appium, appium-android, python-appium

I am getting error 'UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 134, signal null' in the appium server logs.

What is the error code 134 ? could not find any reference for it.

Environment -

Appium version: 1.14.0
Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: macOS 10.14.5
Node.js version: 12.6.0
Mobile platform/version under test: Android
Real device or emulator/simulator: Emulator, Pixel2

Appium Log -

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/8334f2fc-0d96-4ce7-a55f-70369d835d5f/element
[HTTP] {“using”:“xpath”,“value”:"//android.widget.TextView[@text=‘Service Area’]"}
[debug] [W3C (8334f2fc)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: [“xpath”,"//android.widget.TextView[@text=‘Service Area’]",“8334f2fc-0d96-4ce7-a55f-70369d835d5f”]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {“cmd”:“action”,“action”:“find”,“params”:{“strategy”:“xpath”,“selector”:"//android.widget.TextView[@text=‘Service Area’]",“context”:"",“multiple”:false}}

[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {“cmd”:“action”,“action”:“find”,“params”:{“strategy”:“xpath”,“selector”:"//android.widget.TextView[@text=‘Service Area’]",“context”:"",“multiple”:false}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding ‘//android.widget.TextView[@text=‘Service Area’]’ using ‘XPATH’ with the contextId: ‘’ multiple: false
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding ‘//android.widget.TextView[@text=‘Service Area’]’ using ‘XPATH’ with the contextId: ‘’ multiple: false

[UiAutomator] UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 134, signal null

[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state ‘stopped’
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[Appium] Closing session, cause was ‘UiAUtomator shut down unexpectedly’
[Appium] Removing session 8334f2fc-0d96-4ce7-a55f-70369d835d5f from our master session list
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Resetting IME to io.appium.settings/.UnicodeIME
[debug] [ADB] Running ‘/Users/Pranit/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell ime set io.appium.settings/.UnicodeIME’
[debug] [ADB] Running ‘/Users/Pranit/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell am force-stop com.ridecell.platform.phoenix.platform’
[debug] [ADB] Pressing the HOME button
[debug] [ADB] Running ‘/Users/Pranit/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell input keyevent 3’

[AndroidBootstrap] Cannot shut down Android bootstrap; it has already shut down
[debug] [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[debug] [ADB] Running ‘/Users/Pranit/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell am force-stop io.appium.unlock’
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add clearSystemFiles capability if wanted.
[debug] [W3C (8334f2fc)] Encountered internal error running command: Error: UiAUtomator shut down unexpectedly
[debug] [W3C (8334f2fc)] at UiAutomator. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/bootstrap.js:187:42)
[debug] [W3C (8334f2fc)] at UiAutomator.emit (events.js:203:13)
[debug] [W3C (8334f2fc)] at UiAutomator.emit [as changeState] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/uiautomator.js:87:10)
[debug] [W3C (8334f2fc)] at SubProcess.changeState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/uiautomator.js:47:14)
[debug] [W3C (8334f2fc)] at SubProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
[debug] [W3C (8334f2fc)] at ChildProcess.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/teen_process/lib/subprocess.js:153:14)
[debug] [W3C (8334f2fc)] at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
[debug] [W3C (8334f2fc)] at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/8334f2fc-0d96-4ce7-a55f-70369d835d5f/element 500 1982 ms - 565
```

Comment: Not getting the error after splitting the line of code (where I was getting this error) into smaller chunks.
The original line of code had nested functions being called clubbed into one.